# Why does a Highcharts chart disappear after mounting the LiveView a second time?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

Software used:

- Elixir v1.10.2
- Phoenix 1.5.0-rc0
- LiveView 0.12.1
- macOS Cataline 10.15.4
- Tried on Safari and Firefox

I have a LiveView set up nicely with a chart (from Highcharts) showing some data. The chart is enclosed in a div with the `phx-update="ignore"` attribute which works great. However, moving away from the current LiveView and coming back to it makes the chart disappear.

When I first visit the LiveView page:

[image]

After navigating away then coming back with `<%= live_patch "Dashboard, ... %>` or `<%= live_redirect "Dashboard", ... %>`:

[image]

`dashboard_live.html.leex`:

```
<div phx-update="ignore" id="custom-chart">
    <figure id="main-chart" class="highcharts-figure">
        <div class="chart-container" id="<%= @chart_id %>"></div>
    </figure>
    <script id="main-chart-data">
        ....
    </script>
</div>
```

The chart displays normally after I refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

The initialization of the chart must be done through [LiveView hooks](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#module-js-interop-and-client-controlled-dom).

The answer was given in [elixirforums by LostKobrakai](https://elixirforum.com/t/why-does-a-highcharts-chart-disappear-after-mounting-the-liveview-a-second-time/30774/2?u=aesmail)